# Linear regression vs contingency table for poll results

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, discrete-data, polling

Let's assume we made a survey where participants had to evaluate us on a scale from 1 to 5. We want to analyse how different variables (let's say gender or age for instance) have an effect on the answers.

As we have discrete data, my first idea was to use a $\chi^2$-test for independence, however that would not reflect the "order" of the different answers (the test does not care about "3 is the midpoint between 2 and 4" and other similar relationships).

For that matter, I thought about fitting a linear regression model. Apart from that advantage, it is also easier to include multiple variables at the same time. However, I am worried that the discrete nature of the output makes regression unsuitable.

Finally, I considered working on our problem as a multinomial classification one, but we are back at the "ordering" issue.

What is the best way to attack this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic situation calling for a form of [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression). Ordinal regression specifically takes into account the ordering among response categories that you wish to preserve.

There are several ways to implement ordinal regression, depending on how the 5 response levels differ from each other and how those differences are related to differences in the values of the predictor variables. This site's explanation of [`ordered-logit`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ordered-logit/info) models provides a good introduction, describes what a linear regression would mean in this type of situation (sometimes a valid choice), and includes many further references.

Comment: Yes! Ordinal regression is exactly what I was looking for!